# How to create a box to choose size like in the link below with just HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create a field to choose sizes for my page exactly like "Case size" in the link below. I just started learning HTML, CSS, and javascript.

https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch?option.watch_cases=MWT42LL/A&option.watch_bands=MXP72AM/A&preSelect=false&product=Z0YQ&step=detail#

```css
table {
  table-layout:auto; 
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table tr td {
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-size">
  <table id="my-table" onclick="changeBorderColor()">
      <tr>
          <td>40mm</td>
          <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: right;">From $399</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><small>Case fits 130-200mm wrists.</small></td>
      </tr>
  </table><br>

  <table>
      <tr>
          <td>44mm</td>
          <td rowspan="2" style="text-align: right;">From $429</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><small>Case fits 140-220mm wrists.</small></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These pieces of codes should help you. **You do not need JavaScript for doing that. Plain CSS has the necessary logic for this purpose.**

Use a radio input so that only one of the given options can be selected. Checking if the input is checked is done with the CSS pseudo-class selector `:checked`. Using an input removes all the worries for the `onclick` logic you are trying. The `+` selector is *adjacent sibling selector*, it selects its sibling directly next to it.

Talking of functionality, use the `onchange` event handler instead of `onclick`.

Reading the code should explain itself to you. Check out the **Further Reading** section at the bottom of this answer. Don't hesitate to comment your query.

```css
/*Do not focus on the numbers, 
they are taken from the webpage given in your question to match the exact style*/

input.size-button-input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label.size-button-label {
  font-family: 'SF Pro Text', 'Segoe UI', Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.23543;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -.022em;
  color: #333;

  width: 400px;
  min-height: 4.88235rem;
  padding: .70588rem .88235rem;
  margin-top: .82353rem;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;

  border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-spacing: 0;

  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .8);
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.size-button-label .size-text {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.size-button-label .desc {
  margin-top: 4px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.33341;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -.01em;
}

input.size-button-input:checked+label.size-button-label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .11765rem #0070c9;
  border-color: transparent;
}

label.size-button-label:hover {
  border-color: #888;
}

label.size-button-label:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.17647rem rgba(131, 192, 253, .5);
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="size" id="size1" class="size-button-input" onchange="//Your Function" checked>
<label for="size1" class="size-button-label">
  <div class="size-text">40mm
  <div class="desc">Case fits 130-200mm wrists.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="price-text">From $399</div>
</label>

<input type="radio" name="size" id="size2" class="size-button-input" onchange="//Your Function">
<label for="size2" class="size-button-label">
  <div class="size-text">44cm
  <div class="desc">Case fits 140-220mm wrists.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="price-text">From $429</div>
</label>
```

## Further Reading:

- [CSS Selectors: Combinators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#Combinators#Child-combinator) on MDN
- [:checked - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) on MDN
- [:checked](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/) on CSS Tricks
- [onchange event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange) on MDN